# open/close an oracle connection multiple times c#

Tags: c#, oracle

In my business logic, I use multiple oracle query's multiple times. What is the best way to open and close the oracle connection?

```
private void update()
{
     OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Connection Statement");
     OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("Select Statement");
     con.Open();
     OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

     reader.Close();
     con.Close();

     // A for loop

     con.Open();
     command = new OracleCommand("Update statement");
     command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     con.Close();

     con.Open();
     command = new OracleCommand("Second Update statement");
     command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     con.Close();
}
```

My code looks like this. Should I open and close my oracle connection for every command or open before the first command and close after the last command.

P.S. This update function is called over 100 times in my application.

Comment: Here is where using statement comes handy

Comment: Create a separate connection class and from there, just create instance of that class everywhere. But still you have to maintain the connection open and close in that way.

Comment: Why do you reopen the same connection from one line to the next? As for "ideal" the *standard* way is to create the connection inside a `using` block to ensure the connection is closed even if an exception occurs. Connection pooling ensures this is a cheap operation. `using` should be used with data readers as well

Comment: @AT-2017 how would that help?

Comment: As the connection is local to the method create it in a `using` block and then use it as many times as you need to in that block. The block can contain loops or whatever, there is no rule that states you have to discard the connection after you use it once. However connection sharing is discouraged, so **do not** create a class level instance or static instance for shared use.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am a junior developer and heard to close my oracle connection as early as possible. Could you help me making it better?

Comment: If you do see a need to have an instance scoped connection then be sure to also implement IDisposable on that type to clean up the connection after the type is no longer used.

Comment: @Igor Thanks for your suggestion. What should be the scope of an oracle connection to use it in a best way?

Comment: @DineshInavolu - as PanagiotisKanavos already pointed out .net will handle connection pooling by default. You can keep the connection scoped to the code it is used, very seldom will there be a need to move it to a higher scope like the class level (ie. a field) unless you need to execute and track multiple operations on a single connection & transaction.

Comment: @DineshInavolu `as early as possible` but not earlier. If you *reopen* it right after closing, you're just wasting time. In any case, start with ADO.NET courses and tutorials, don't follow advice blindly. You need to understand *why* connections shouldn't remain open for long (they accumulate locks) or what connection pooling is. Why you should use parameterized queries instead of concatenating strings to create a query (that's what leads to SQL injection).

Comment: @DineshInavolu you can find many online (and free) tutorials in Microsoft's own Micorosoft Virtual Academy. You can get 3 months free access to Pluralsight's courses through Microsoft's (also free) [Visual Studio Dev Essentials](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/dev-essentials/) program. Check for example Herve Roggero's [ADO.NET Fundamentals](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/adodotnet-fundamentals) course

Comment: You should also check [ADO.NET's own doc site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/). ADO.NET uses base classes and class factories that allow you to write more-or-less database agnostic code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the connection is local to the method create it in a `using` block and then use it as many times as you need to in that block. The block can contain loops or whatever, there is no rule that states you have to discard the connection after you use it once.

However connection sharing is discouraged, so **do not** create a class level instance or static instance for shared use.

```
private void update()
{
     using(OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Connection Statement"))
     {
         con.Open();
         using(var command = new OracleCommand("Select Statement", con))
         using(OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()}
         {

         }

         // A for loop

         using(var command = new OracleCommand("Update statement", con))
         {
           command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }

         using(var command = new OracleCommand("Second Update statement", con))
         {
           command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
     }
}
```